# Writing a regex-based lexer - regex doesn't match input

Tags: .net, regex

I'm writing a lexer/tokenizer for CSS, as per this syntax specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#syntax

I have a sample stylesheet that I'm attempting to tokenize, specified here:

```
const String css = @"

foo bar {
    property: value;
    property2: value2;
    /* comment1 */
}
        ";
```

My lexer iterates through every regular expression on each iteration and it correctly captures the initial whitespace token, however the `Ident` regex fails to capture the `"foo"` text. Here is my regex:

```
public const String Ident    = "[-]?" + Nmstart + Nmchar + "*";
public const String Nmstart  = "[_a-z]|" + Nonascii + "|" + Escape;
public const String Nmchar   = @"[_a-z0-9-]|" + Nonascii + "|" + Escape;
public const String Nonascii = @"[^\0-\237]";
public const String Escape   = Unicode + @"\\[^\n\r\f0-9a-f]";
public const String Unicode  = @"\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \n\r\t\f])?";
```

The `Ident` regex expands to this (escaped):

```
[-]?[_a-z]|[^\\0-\\237]|\\\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\\r\\n|[ \\n\\r\\t\\f])?\\\\[^\\n\\r\\f0-9a-f][_a-z0-9-]|[^\\0-\\237]|\\\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\\r\\n|[ \\n\\r\\t\\f])?\\\\[^\\n\\r\\f0-9a-f]*
```

or this (unescaped, verbatim):

```
[-]?[_a-z]|[^\0-\237]|\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \n\r\t\f])?\\[^\n\r\f0-9a-f][_a-z0-9-]|[^\0-\237]|\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \n\r\t\f])?\\[^\n\r\f0-9a-f]*
```

My regex matches the expression in the CSS specification (I think), so why isn't it matching `"foo"`?

#### Update:

On leppi's suggestion I added parenthesis, resulting in this:

```
public const String Ident= "[-]?(" + Nmstart + ")(" + Nmchar + ")*";
```

...however it still doesn't match.

Comment: I think you might need to be a bit more liberal with grouping parenthesis.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please? :)

Comment: Easy way, just add `(` `)` around every token definition. It makes stuff like `a|b*|c?` more predictable.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Am I doing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solution was twofold:

First, Leppi's suggestion that I group the `Nmstart` and `Nmchar` macros was correct.

Secondly, I needed to use the `"\G"` prefix instead of the `"^"` prefix, as I was using the `Match(String, Int32)` overload.